# Send HTTP request through proxy server to Internet

Tags: proxy, https, redirect, squid, tinyproxy

I have a client that has no direct access to the internet. But it is connected to a server on a LAN connection, whereas the server has access to the Internet.

I'd like to send an HTTP request from the client through the Server to the Internet. How can I do this?

```
+--------+        +--------+        +--------+
|        |  LAN   | Ubuntu |   WAN  |        |
| Client <--------> 16.04  <-------->  WWW   |
|        |        | Server |        |        |
+--------+        +--------+        +--------+
```

Steps:

1. Client sends request to Server on LAN at https://user:pass@local-server:1234
2. Server forwards request to remote endpoint at https://user:pass@remote-server

Note: I only need to forward the HTTP request to a single endpoint

I have been looking at running [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) or [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/) on the server but I'm not sure how to properly configure them or if it's the simplest approach. Is a proxy server needed here?

Answer (score 3):

There is two solutions. First - configure NAT on server, Second - configure HTTP Proxy. So, from my point of view, for your situation best way - configure NAT, you don't need to install any additional software, just configure firewall.

To configure it on `iptables` you should do two steps:

First of all make sure the packet forwarding is enabled in the kernel

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

You can also make it permanent by adding below line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Then you should add to `iptables` configuration two rules:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination internet-ip:1234
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j MASQUERADE
```

It could be done by command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination internet-ip:1234
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j MASQUERADE
```

With this you should check that there is no rule for forwarding block, it looks like this `-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`. If it exist, it could be removed by command:

```
iptables -t filter -D FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

As well, you could read articles for enabling forwarding in `ufw` in internet. Here two[[1]](https://gist.github.com/kimus/9315140)[[2]](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-ufw-to-forward-port-80443-to-internal-server-hosted-on-lan/) examples.

Comment: Correct options. Insufficient justification of recommendation.

Comment: @DanielWidrick it's hard to recommend anything, because I don't know what Linux distributive and what firewall use topic starter.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev can you give some more details on how I could do this?

Comment: @RyanR I know how to configure `iptables`. If it's ok for you, I could write simple configuration.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev yes that would be helpful to get me started, thanks.

Comment: @RyanR, please check updated answer.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev thanks I will try and report back.

Comment: Upvoting after edit. I still think a proxy may be more appropriate here but this solution will work.